# How do I stack these divs on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I have searched all over Stackoverflow and no solution has worked so far. I need a quick tip or help in order to figure out how would I go about stacking the div id "top_section" on the of the div id "middle_section". right now "middle_section" is on top of "top_section" when it should really be at the bottom right right where "top_section" ends is where "middle_section" should begin.

**Heres the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top_section">
     <div class="content_wrapper">

        <section id="td_left">
            <h1>XYZ</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="td_right"></section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle_section">
        <div class="content_wrapper">
            <h1>Stuff</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom_section"></div>
  </div>
```

**Heres the CSS:**

```
.content_wrapper {
 width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: red; }

 header {
  background: blue; }
  header img {
  width: 14%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }

 .sections, #top_section, #middle_section {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left; }

  #top_section {
   height: 80.3%;
   background: #34495D; }

   #middle_section {
    height: 70.3%;
    background: #21303F; }
```

Comment: Like adding `top: 80.3%`? http://jsfiddle.net/v778cahq/

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.sections, #top_section, #middle_section {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left; 
  }
```

to

```
.sections, #top_section, #middle_section {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to satisfy the OP requirement: "where 'top_section' ends is where 'middle_section' should begin". Check the gap between the divs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/euL6boez/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use "top" to define where the section should start.
Dont forget the height of your section have to be 100% or less if you add them to each other.

```
#top_section {
   top: 0%
   height: 20%;
   background: #34495D; }

  #middle_section {
   top: 20%;
   height: 80%;
   background: #21303F; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get rid of your `position: absolute`.

So your code would have

```
sections, #top_section, #middle_section {
    width: 100%;
    float: left; }
```

instead of

```
.sections, #top_section, #middle_section {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left; 
  }
```

[Heres' a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euL6boez/1/)